# Map array inside computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So I wanted to see if I can get some guidance from the community if there is a better way to approach this:

So I have the following `vue.js` app:

```
new Vue({
    name: 'o365-edit-modal-wrapper',
    el: '#o365-modal-edit-wrapper',
    data: function() {
        const default_apps = [
            {
                'post_title': 'Excel',
            }, {
                'post_title': 'Word',
            }, {
                'post_title': 'SharePoint',
        }];

        return {
            available_list: [],
            selected_list: default_apps.map(function(name, index) {
                return { name: name.post_title, order: index + 1, fixed: false };
            }),
        }
    },
    computed: {
        dragOptions() {
            // Pass in additional <draggable> options inside the return for both lists.
            return {
                tag: 'div',
                group: 'o365apps',
                disabled: !this.editable,
                ghostClass: "ghost",
            };
        },
    },
});
```

The `selected_list` returns the following items:
[image]

I was told that it's bad practice to do array mapping inside the data return, but to instead map inside the computed call - Could someone lead me in the right direction and just see if my code makes sense?

I tried defining an empty array as shown below:

```
return {
    available_list: [],
    selected_list:[],
}
```

& then inside the computed property, I tried accessing it using the following return but wasn't getting any data back:

```
selected_list() {
  return this.default_apps.map(function(name, index) {
      return { name: name.post_title, order: index + 1, fixed: false };
  });
},
```

All help is appreciated - Thanks a bunch!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your are almost there except for a few details:

1. It's ok to map data inside `data` as long as you put them inside the return object literal `data() { return { default_apps: [] } }`.
2. Once `default_apps` is inside the return object of `data`, you can access the data inside of it from a computed property using the `this` keyword: `this.default_apps.map()...`

```
new Vue({
    name: 'o365-edit-modal-wrapper',
    el: '#o365-modal-edit-wrapper',
    data: function() {
      return {
        default_apps: [
          { post_title: 'Excel' }, 
          { post_title: 'Word' },
          { post_title: 'SharePoint'}
        ],
        available_list: [],
      }
    },
  computed: {
      selected_list() {
        return this.default_apps.map(function(name, index) {
          return { name: name.post_title, order: index + 1, fixed: false };
        });
      },
      dragOptions() {
        // Pass in additional <draggable> options inside the return for both lists.
        return {
          tag: 'div',
          group: 'o365apps',
          disabled: !this.editable,
          ghostClass: "ghost",
        };
      },
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Firmino! I'm new to vue, so I'm learning as I make progress, so this is much appreciated - I will test things now.

Comment: Keep up, you'll get there in no time!

Comment: I have a question Firmino, so it works great, but as soon as I drag the items into the other array, seems like it becomes undefined. Would you possibly know a reason behind that?

Comment: Would you please share the logic responsible for the dragging action?

Comment: Sure thing let me make a jsfiddle really quickly.

Comment: here is what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/Semirxbih/dxfc3L70/8/

Comment: I also posted a new picture at the end of the post.